# How do I open an NSWindow and have the window selected and in focus?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I am trying to open a NSWindow using the following code:

```
NSWindowController *window = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
[window showWindow:nil];
```

The window opens okay but the previous window is still the mainWindow and in focus.  I have tried the following code to force the main window and it doesn't work.  The window still has a disabled title bar and isn't accepting key events etc.

```
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[self.window makeMainWindow];
```

The only way I seem to be able to get the previous window to lose focus is if I close the window after calling showWindow: with [[NSApp mainWindow] close];

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why I received a -1 here, anyone let me know how I could improve the question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`makeKeyAndOrderFront:` is the way to go. Are you sure that `self.window` and `window` refer the same object?

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work.  I added the [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]; call straight after the showWindow: and it still doesn't work.  Should I be calling this somewhere else?

Comment: `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` is the right method. It shouldn't matter where you call it. Something else is the problem. For instance, the main window might be modal, or something is refusing to give up first responder status.

Comment: Yes, there was a problem within the nib, see my answer for the solution.

Comment: This worked fine along with showWindow: once the nib was setup correctly.

Comment: @TylerA.  See my answer below

Answer (score 8):

I resolved the issue by assigning the WindowController to the nib File Owner, instead of having a separate NSWindowController object within the nib.

Comment: I would like to add one point to this, I forgot to connect the window outlet to my NSWindow in Interface Builder. This led to the code not working for me, so to anyone reading this, don't forget to connect the window outlet. A simple mistake, but one that can leave you frustrated for ages lol

Comment: Obviously a very old answer, but if anyone could translate this sentence into an image of what this looks like (as opposed to what I think it should look like, which is obviously wrong because it doesn't work), it would be super helpful.